# Вставка токена(##) в строку

Tags: c++, макросы, define

Возник такой вопрос: как вставить с помощью #define какое-либо имя, название и т.п. в строчку, т.е.

```
#include <iostream>
#define GREETING(Name) std::cout << "Hi, Name##!";
int main() {
    GREETING(Nick);
    return 0;
}
```

Хотелось бы чтобы после компиляции программа выводила "Hi, Nick!", но она выведет "Hi, Name##!". Как вывести строчку нормально с define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`##` служит для склейки токенов, однако она тут не нужна, так как строковые литералы склеиваются сами, достаточно только преобразовать аргумент макроса в литерал посредством `#`

```
#include <iostream>
#define GREETING(Name) std::cout << "Hi, " #Name "!";
int main() {
    GREETING(Nick);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#define GREETING(Name) std::cout << "Hi, " << #Name << "!\n";
int main() {
    GREETING(Nick);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Макросы - ещё одна возможность выстрелить себе в ногу!
Проще и правильней с помощью функций. Компилятор при оптимизации скорее всего её заинлайнит:

```
#include <iostream>

void Greeting(const char* Name) { std::cout << "Hi, " << Name << "!";}

int main() 
{
    Greeting("Nick");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я детский пример здесь привёл, мне это нужно для объявления 10 одинаковых тестов, которые отличаются названиями тестов и методов. Писать 10 объявлений подряд не очень...